# Bulk Insert with filename parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I need to load a couple of thousands of data files into SQL Server table.
So I write a stored procedure that receives just one parameter - file name.
But.. The following doesn't work.. The "compiler" complains on @FileName parameter.. It wants just plain string.. like 'file.txt'.
Thanks in advance.

Ilan.

```
BULK INSERT TblValues
FROM @FileName
WITH 
(
FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a pure SQL solution, or are you able to use C#/VB?

Comment: Thanks Paul! I already found something
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050790/bulk-insert-using-stored-procedure

Comment: @IIan, if you have the answer please close the question, and next time search SO for similar questions before asking one.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[The syntax for BULK INSERT statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) is :

```
BULK INSERT 
   [ database_name. [ schema_name ] . | schema_name. ] [ table_name | view_name ] 
      FROM 'data_file' 
     [ WITH
```

So, the file name must be a string constant.
To solve the problem please use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT TblValues FROM ''' + @FileName + ''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR ='','', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )';
EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: That exactly what I did. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050790/bulk-insert-using-stored-procedure

Comment: What about SQL Injection?