# Error 'WITH Statement' in Bulk SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am having problem with the stored procedure that I created. I got a syntax error with **Incorrect syntax near '@path'**.

If I put the absolute path 'J:\TestCSV\ImportData.csv' I don't received any error. But if I declare parameters, I received this error that I mentioned above. Here's my stored procedure. Hoping for your helping hand.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[FileUpload]

 As
BEGIN


DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256); -- path   
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256); -- filename   
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20); -- used for file date
SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) ;
SET @fileName = 'ImportData' + '_' + @fileDate + '.csv';
SET @path = 'J:\TestCSV\' + @fileName;

BULK

INSERT [dbo].[temp_Cemetery]
--FROM 'E:\CSVTest\ImportDataYYYYMMDD.csv'
FROM @path  -- Error Here Incorrect syntax near '@path'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)


END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk Insert with filename parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306616/bulk-insert-with-filename-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a string literal for some reason. You'll probably have to use dynamic sql e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FileUpload]
AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256); -- path   
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256); -- filename   
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20); -- used for file date
SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) ;
SET @fileName = 'ImportData' + '_' + @fileDate + '.csv';
SET @path = 'J:\\TestCSV\\' + @fileName;
DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)

SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[temp_Cemetery]
FROM ''' + @path + '''
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
)'

EXEC (@sql)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you needed to escape the backslash near the quote:

```
SET @path = 'J:\\TestCSV\\' + @fileName;
```

This is because the backslash is a special character and since you escaped the single quote it treated the rest of the statement as part of the string. I fixed it for you below.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[FileUpload]

 As
BEGIN


DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256); -- path   
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256); -- filename   
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20); -- used for file date
SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) ;
SET @fileName = 'ImportData' + '_' + @fileDate + '.csv';
SET @path = 'J:\\TestCSV\\' + @fileName;

BULK

INSERT [dbo].[temp_Cemetery]
--FROM 'E:\CSVTest\ImportDataYYYYMMDD.csv'
FROM @path  -- Error Here Incorrect syntax near '@path'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)


END
```

Comment: Still having same error.Incorrect syntax near '@path'.
Msg .319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MPGUpload, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes to the path so that your `FROM` clause reads it as `'J:\TestCSV\ImportData_20170104.csv'` instead of `J:\TestCSV\ImportData_20170104.csv`

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[FileUpload]

 As
BEGIN


DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256); -- path   
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256); -- filename   
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20); -- used for file date
SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) ;
SET @fileName = 'ImportData' + '_' + @fileDate + '.csv';
SET @path = '''J:\TestCSV\' + @fileName +'''';



BULK
INSERT [dbo].[temp_Cemetery]
--FROM 'E:\CSVTest\ImportDataYYYYMMDD.csv'
FROM @path  -- Error Here Incorrect syntax near '@path'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)


END
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.