# Entity Framework ExecuteSqlCommand BULK INSERT with parameter: am I doing this wrong?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My code:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    @"BULK INSERT dbo.tblAudit FROM @FileName WITH (FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR='|', ROWTERMINATOR='\n')",
    new SqlParameter("@FileName", auditCsvFileName)
    );
```

It should perform a bulk insert from a csv file.

It throws an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '@FileName'

I can run this command (with the filename inserted) in SSMS without an error.

1. Is this an invalid use of parameters?
2. Does Entity Framework not support `BULK INSERT` as a raw SQL command?

Thanks

Comment: `BULK INSERT` does not support parameters anywhere. You'll have to use textual replacement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306616/bulk-insert-with-filename-parameter

Comment: Perhaps, using [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/)?

Comment: I agree, I've duplicated [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306616/bulk-insert-with-filename-parameter). Thanks.